# P(E) of union of pairwise events

Tags: probability

Let $F_1,...,F_n$ be pairwise disjoint events, and $\Omega = F_1 \cup...\cup F_n$.

Show

$P(E) = \sum _{j=1}^nP(E|F_j)F(F_j)$

I don't really understand how to get $P(E)$ in this case.

I know $P(E)=\frac{P(E|F)P(F)}{P(F|E)}$, but I can't figure out how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is the disjoint union of the events $E \cap F_j$. Hence $P(E)= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} P(E\cap F_j)$ Now use the fact that $P(E\cap F_j)=P(E|F_j)P(F_j)$.